# Contact sub-type not populated in front end profile

Tags: profile

I have a profile for existing users where they can select their contact sub-type. Submitting the form updates their contact sub-type, but it isn't populated when they view the form. Any ideas as to why that might be? There is a mix of contact and individual fields on there, but Civi doesn't complain about it.

Civi 5.65.2
WordPress 6.4.2

Comment: are you able to replicate a very simple equivalent on one of the demo sites which is using the latest code eg https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tested it on the demo site and it worked. Tracked the issue down to our WordPress theme :)

Comment: Great. perhaps add as an answer so this can be marked as Answered